# Operador Logico AND &&

Tags: c, condiciones, operador, char

Hola queria un poco de ayuda.. estaba intentando y aprendiento AND OR Y NOT , pero los ejemplos son siempre comparando con "numeros" hay alguna forma de hacer con "texto" o una "palabra"  por ahorita se que es mas facil utilizar "if" "else" pero queria ver si este codigo puede funcionar de alguna manera.y si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char r[10],b[10];
printf("Escribe rojo ");
scanf("%s",r);
printf("Escribe blanco : ");
scanf("%s",b);
if(r="rojo" && b="blanco")
{
printf(" Esta bien");
}
else
{
printf(" Esta mal ");
}
}
```

Comment: Revisa la condición dentro del if. Me parece que es más adecuado comparar con la función strcmp. Por otra parte, el operador de igualdad es ==, no =.  = es el operador de asignación. Te dejo estas referencias, por si te son de ayuda: https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/c/c-compare-strings/  https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-language/c-relational-and-equality-operators?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

para palabras en C, lo mejor es utilizar la librería **string.h** que añade funciones para gestionar cadenas de texto.
En tu caso, como quieres comparar tendrías que utilizar la función `strcmp(<cadena1>, cadena2)`, esta función lo que hace es comparar ambas cadenas y devolver un 0 si son idénticas, un número negativo si la cadena1 es menor que la cadena2 y, y un número positivo si es al revés. Por lo tanto tu código sería así.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char r[10],b[10];
    printf("Escribe rojo ");
    scanf("%s",r);
    printf("Escribe blanco : ");
    scanf("%s",b);

    if(strcmp(r, b) == 0) {
        printf(" Esta bien");
    } else {
        printf(" Esta mal ");
    }
}
```

Y como dato extra, recuerda, el **==** es para comparar lo que está a la izquierda con lo que está a la derecha y es lo que se utiliza en los condicionales, el **=** es para asignar valores a variables.